# list-vaults permission on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-glacier

If I log in into EC2 instance and try to issue the command

```
aws glacier list-vaults --account-id ######
```

I get an error that the user doesn't have permission, I was able to give the IAM users the right permissions and it works perfectly from the local machine. But it doesn't work from within the EC2 instance.

Where do I add the permission? Who is the actual user that issue the command from withing an EC2 instance (for example "aws s3" commands work without a problem)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If some other aws cli commands do work for you, the most likely reason is, that there is an [Instance Profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html) attached to the instance.

Instance profiles are created from EC2 roles. To find out which IAM role is used for the profile, use

```
aws sts get-caller-identity --query Arn
```

The output looks like this:

```
"arn:aws:sts::$accountID:assume-role/$rolename/$instanceID"
```

where `$instanceID`is the name of the IAM role you are looking for. Your need to add the IAM permission `glacier:ListVaults` to this role.

Comment: Thanks. I added the permission to the role and it worked.

Comment: Did not help, the user returned from sts command has full glacier:* policy on * resources, but the issue with list-vaults on CLI access is still same